# How do you manage non-automatable compliance and tasks in code reviews?

Tags: workflow, standards-compliance, github-codereviews

We all appreciate the utility of automated checks during code reviews, such as linting, type checking, or security scans. However, there are certain compliance requirements or tasks that can't easily be automated.

Some examples I can think of are:

Recording size/impact of a change or notifying a specific team prior to merging a PR.

I'd love to hear about the best practices, tools, or workflows anyone employs to manage these non-automatable aspects of code review. It'd be awesome to learn about the specific use case too

I've tried using templates but people just ignore them